# ASP.Net Core (version 5.0) AuthorizationHandler not being called - always 403 forbidden response for SignalR

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr, signalr-hub, asp.net-core-signalr

Custom AuthorizationHandler is not being called when Authorize attribute is placed at method level on SignalR Hub implementation.

I have the following code, with what I believe to be the correct inclusion for custom authorization handling. I am using the following setup:

ASP.Net Core version 5.0,
.Net 5.0 console app with Kestrel host configure for Windows Authentication (the Identity is populated):

Any ideas what is missing/wrong?

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        
        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => endpoints.MapHub<ExampleHub>("/Example"));
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddNegotiate();

        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(nameof(ExampleRequirement), policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new ExampleRequirement()));
        });

        services.AddSingleton<IUserIdProvider, NameUserIdProvider>();
        services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationRequirement, ExampleAuthorizationRequirementHandler>();

        services.AddSignalR(options =>
        {
            options.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
        });
    }
}

public class ExampleRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
}

public class ExampleAuthorizationRequirementHandler : AuthorizationHandler<ExampleRequirement, HubInvocationContext>, IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, ExampleRequirement requirement,
        HubInvocationContext resource)
    {
        context.Succeed(requirement);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

public class NameUserIdProvider : IUserIdProvider
{
    public string GetUserId(HubConnectionContext connection)
    {
        return connection.User?.Identity?.Name;
    }
}

public class ExampleHub : Hub
{
    [Authorize(Policy = "ExampleRequirement")]
    public Task Register()
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Comment: try moving services.AddSignalR after services.AddAuthorization but before registering the IAuthorizationRequirement

Comment: thanks, but no luck still the same...

Answer (score 0):

Re-ordering the `ConfigureServices` declarations to put the `AddSignalR` at the star, caused this to start working when using Kestrel, not sure about other Asp.Net hosts:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.AddSignalR(options =>
   {
      options.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
   });

   services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
       .AddNegotiate();
   services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(nameof(ExampleRequirement), policy =>                                              policy.Requirements.Add(new ExampleRequirement()));
        });

   services.AddSingleton<IUserIdProvider, NameUserIdProvider>();
   services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationRequirement, ExampleAuthorizationRequirementHandler>();       
}
```